# Which way does power flow on USB type-c if CC1 and CC2 are not connected?

Tags: usb-c

I got my hands on some USB type-c Male connectors, but when I tore one apart I saw that there is no pin on CC1 or CC2 and thus no pull-up or pull-down. After doing some research I'm not sure I know if this connector can draw power or source power.

What behavior is defined in this instance?

Answer (score 3):

Unlike the classic USB Type-A-B connectivity (where the USB host always have VBUS on), the default state of VBUS power on Type-C connector is **always OFF** until the Type-C receptacle sees any (valid) signaling on CC lines. If CC are not connected, it means that nothing is connected, and none of "partner's ports" would output any power. So there will be no way for any power.

Answer (score 2):

CC1 and CC2 open means nothing is connected

Comment: as in no power flow either way?

Comment: Most likely not. The device would not see that anything is plugged in. So it would not know what to do, provide power or consume power.

Answer (score 0):

For an USB C plug with CC disconnected, according to section A Audio Adapter Accessory Mode, it is able to source up to 500mA. This is defined in the [USB C 2.0 spec page 309](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB%20Type-C%20Spec%20R2.0%20-%20August%202019.pdf)

For an USB C receptacle supporting the audio adapter mode, if it sees 5V VBUS on an USB C receptacle without any CC connectivity, it means it is connected to an audio adapter mode, so any device supporting this mode can charge at 500mA

Comment: But to go into audio adapter mode, the audio adapter must pulls both CC pins low, 0 to 1 kohm range, so how can it be open/disconnected?

Comment: Page 313 of the above specification shows an example schematic. Both CC pins are connected together, and then towards the detection pin of the audio jack. If nothing is being plugged into the audio jack, then the CC pins are only shorted, but not connected via an Ra to ground (Once an audio cable is being plugged in, (Both CC pins read Ra the device can do its AGND/MIC wire detection protocol) Note that the description states charging should be available with and without an audio jack being plugged in